# Парсер 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, парсер

Друзья помогите парсить [этот url](https://detailskip.taobao.com/service/getData/1/p1/item/detail/sib.htm?itemId=547342551736&sellerId=1049985701&modules=dynStock,qrcode,viewer,price,contract,duty,xmpPromotion,delivery,upp,activity,fqg,zjys,couponActivity,soldQuantity&callback=onSibRequestSuccess)
на php

[Этого товара](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=547342551736)

там 403 Forbidden но браузер как то вытаскивает. тут обычный парсер curl не поможет думаю.

Comment: Curl это не парсер, а http-клиент. Вам нужно парсить URL или парсить HTML, которым отвечает сервер при запросе по данному URL?

Comment: вы бы написали, как со второй ссылки на первую попасть.

Comment: Да правильно, нужно парсит данные первого url,а